# android rotate image crashes only on certain phones

Tags: android, image, crash, rotation

I have an android app that allows users to take photos.  In that effort, the image is not always correctly displayed, depending on the phone's orientation during image capture.  I have provided a rotate image feature that works on most, but not all phones.  In fact, when it does not work the app crashes.  The rotate feature is provided below.  I appreciate any feedback that can get this to work on all phones.  Also, the app just crashes and the error trap is not invoked.

```
private void rotateImage(float degrees){

     try{

         String imageFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+Imagefile;
         Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile);                       
         int width = bitmap.getWidth();
         int height = bitmap.getHeight();

         // resize the bit map
         //matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

         // rotate the Bitmap
         Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
         matrix.postRotate(degrees);             
         // create the new Bitmap                         
         Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);                 

         imageAsset.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);

         // clean up 
         bitmap = null;
         rotatedBitmap = null;
         matrix = null;

     }catch(Exception e){
        utility.logError(this,"{"+CLASS_NAME+"}[rotateImage] Error:  "+e.getMessage());         
     }
 }
```

Comment: What is the error? You should post the relevan part of logcat and possibly code that produces the error.

Comment: No error message.  It just crashes.  Since I cannot afford to purchase every phone model, I can only rely on user feedback sometimes.

Comment: Don't you have any report in the Android Market Console? Just tell the user complaining to send a report!

Comment: No report from market.  The user is one of my national sales reps who has side loaded a beta version to help resolve this issue.  I have no ability to mount the phone in a development environment.  Since the app crashes, all error telemetry on this particular issue is not captured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably put of memory error. The available heap depends on the type of phone. Even though the bitmaps are stored in native memory (which makes their memory consuption harder to track) they are limited to the same heap size. Big bitmaps (from a 5MP) camera easily use up all the memory in an app. 
You would have to post your error log to be sure though.

For starters:
- use smaller images

- to clean up bitmaps use bitmap.recycle();

Edit:
ok, thinking about it im pretty sure it's the out-of-memory. That's why the error doesn't get caught, because it happens in native code.

This is what you do:

When you decode your image resample it to a smaller size:

```
BitmapFactory.Options resample = new BitmapFactory.Options();
resample.inSampleSize = 4;  // whatever number seems apropriate 4 means 1/4 of the original
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile, resample);
```

Comment: I use the smallest available resolution on the phone.  If that uses all memory then there are far larger issues.

Comment: its not the resolution of the display that matters. When you load the bitmap (decode file) that was taken by the camera, it loads a very huge image wich then gets scaled down to fit your screen. But no way to be sure without the error log.

Comment: If I set the camera parms to use the lowest available resolution, then why would it save the file at the maximum resolution?  What's the point of setting the cam parms if they will be ignored?  Or, are they just for previewing?

Comment: Any way to determine the picture size before loading so that I can appropriate adjust the resample to the respective phone's abilities?  On my Nexus One, the images are now really tiny!

Comment: BitmapFactory.Options.inJustDecodeBounds(true); can be used to decode the bitmap so that you can read out the dimensions without loading the actual thing into memory.

Comment: Since we are not sure at this point weather it's really an oom. Add Log.d("whatever", "size= " + width + "x" + height); below your int height = bitmap.getHeight(); and see what it says. If it's something big like 2000x2300 then its the memory.

Comment: It has been determined to be an oom error.  Thanks, you were spot on, the images were huge.  Thanks for the file peek too.

Answer (score 1):

androidika may be on to something. [Try](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle%28%29):

```
bitmap.recycle();
rotatedBitmap.recycle();
```

Comment: I am evaluating yours and androidika's response. However, since this is not happening on a phone I have direct control over, it can take some time.

Comment: does the user feedback give you details on the phone which was in use? You can create custom avd's to simulate the unique features of these devices.

Comment: Yes.  The phone in question is the Motorola Droid 2 Global.  I have looked to specs to create an emulator, but have not found all.  Any suggestions on where I can get all the specs to create a MD2G?

Comment: uh search engines? I found this on my 2nd page: http://www.phonearena.com/phones/Motorola-DROID-2-Global_id4842

The important part is that there is 512 MB RAM and 480 x 854 px, 3.70 in screen.

Comment: Thanks for the obvious, but perhaps I should have been more clear.  The emulator does not have resolutions enumerated like an actual phone - you can only specify one supported resolution.  When capturing an image from the phone emulator, only the stock image is provided.  Therefore, how exactly do you emulate the phone precisely when the behavior is very different?

Comment: Also, let please keep the comments constructive.  I appreciate your help, but communicating via threads is not always clear to both parties.  Superlatives are not necessary.  Thanks.  :^)